# Knockout foreach no access to object

Tags: knockout.js

i´m struggling arround with this problem for hours now and i have no idea

i´m having an observable array thats initially empty, heres a reduced version :

```
var AppModel = function(data){
    var self=this;

    self.found=ko.observable(   
      {      
        hits:ko.observableArray([])
      }
    );    

};
```

on some point later i get some result from api in plain json

```
console.dir(response.data.hits);
self.found().hits(response.data.hits);
```

this is the output of console.dir :

![console dir][1]

when i now type in console :

```
appModel.found().hits()
```

it returns :

![enter image description here][2]

so everything looks pretty fine

what i want to do is a foreach binding :

```
            <div data-bind="foreach: found().hits()">
                <div class="box">
                    <p data-bind="value: $data.id" ></p>
                    <p data-bind="value: JSON.stringify($data)" ></p>
                    <p data-bind="value: id" ></p>
                    <p data-bind="value: nameFull" ></p>
                    <p data-bind="value: $data.nameFull" ></p>
                    <p data-bind="value: function(){ return this.nameFull }" ></p>

                </div>
            </div>
```

and ".box" gets rendered 10 times but theres no value in the

tags

looking like :

[image]

so you see i´m not able to access the properties, what am i doing wrong ?

unfoirtunatly i cant setup a fiddle,
someone has an idea ? i really tryed everything i know .. and i made a lot of foreach bindings before, i have absolutely no idea

Comment: `unfoirtunatly[sic] i cant setup a fiddle` why not? It would be a lot easier for people to help you if you help them.

Comment: @MattBurland i tryed http://jsfiddle.net/qz5fe8fy/  but i have no idea whats wrong, when you type "appModel" in console its not defined, "data" also is not defined, so i stopped it

Comment: Of course it's not available in the console. You have everything wrapped in a closure (which is probably wrapped in a closure by JS Fiddle anyway).

Comment: if i change "value" to "text" my fiddle works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind `text` not `value` for a `p` type. Value binding is for `input` types.

Example:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: found().hits">
    <div class="box">
        <p data-bind="text: id"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: nameFull"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvz5fkpy/

Docs on value binding:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

> This is typically useful with form elements such as `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`.

Docs on text binding:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html

> Typically this is useful with elements like `<span>` or `<em>` that traditionally display text, but technically you can use it with any element.